# Teamcity insists on publishing with the "debug" configuration

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, msdeploy

So. My problem is as follows:

I am working on a medium size web site in Visual Studio 2013. Whenever I do a check in, TeamCity is publishing my website to Azure. All this works as expected, but now that we have been working on the project for a while, we want to do a publish to a demo server as well.
I have created a configuration in the Visual Studio Configuration Manager called `Deploy-Test`, and have a working publish profile called `Deploy-Demo.pubxml`.

In my `build.proj` file I have the following target:

```
<Target Name="DeployDemoWebsite" DependsOnTargets="VersionAssemblies">
    <Message Text="Deploying $(ProjectName) Demo Website" />
    <MSBuild Projects="Source\$(ProjectName).sln" Targets="Build" Properties="DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile=Deploy-Demo;Configuration=Deploy-Demo;" />
    <Message Text="Deployed $(ProjectName) Demo Website!" />
</Target>
```

Also, in the `pubxml`-file, I have specified the configuration:

```
<LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Deploy-Demo</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
```

Everything is working **except** web.config transformations.

Whenever I do a check in, Teamcity starts to build and deploy the new version, but in the build log, I see the following:

```
[11:24:35][Source\WebUi\WebUi.csproj] TransformWebConfigCore
[11:24:35]    [TransformWebConfigCore] TransformXml
[11:24:35]        [TransformXml] Transforming Source File: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\855eef14c36558c5\Source\WebUi\Web.config
[11:24:35]        [TransformXml]   Applying Transform File: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\855eef14c36558c5\Source\WebUi\Web.Debug.config
[11:24:35]        [TransformXml]   Output File: obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config
[11:24:35]        [TransformXml] Transformation succeeded
```

If I use the Publish menu item in Visual Studio and publish to file system, it all works as expected, and my web.config gets transformed using the expected transformation file.

I have tried setting the parameter in TeamCity under `Build Step: MSBuild`. It did not help.

Have any of you ever experienced this?

Comment: Specifically for TeamCity, have you tried configuring a system parameter called `system.Configuration` with value `Deploy-Demo`?  This value will be used to bootstrap the MSBuild process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the Configuration value as a part of your build process. It cannot be set in the .pubxml. More details on my blog http://sedodream.com/2012/10/27/MSBuildHowToSetTheConfigurationProperty.aspx.